# Dynamic caller give error MissingMethodException: Method 'Clock.TEST' not found

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, system.reflection

**Brief introduction:**
Currently developing a videogames/leraning project in unity whit c#, i have some issues and cant use system.windows.forms neither the system.therading, so i decide to make my own clock and have more control.

i want that this clock have a dynamic caller per tick, so when it ticks a method from another object is called, using system.reflection and many blogs and sites for reference i found how to make it call methods from the same object whit the unity invoke, i want this to call any method in the game, like the system.windows.forms, at this point i make this:

```
public object InvokeByName(string typeName, string methodName, object target)
{
    Type callType = Type.GetType(typeName);
    Binder defaultBinder = Type.DefaultBinder;
    return callType.InvokeMember(methodName, 
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public, 
                defaultBinder, target , new object[] { });
}

public void Tick(string method, string methodName, object target)
{
    InvokeByName(method, methodName, target);
}


public void Set_Tick(string typeName, string methodName, object target)
{
    this.typeName = typeName;
    this.methodName = methodName;
    this.target = target;
}

public void TEST()
{
    Debug.Log("TEST");
}
```

the issue here is the method isnt capable of finding the method tick, when i set the tick to `clock.Set_Tick("Clock", "TEST", clock);`

this should execute the method Clock.TEST but for some reason it is incapable of finding the method, i try almost everything and also read similar cuestions in stack but they arent suited for this issue, ideas?

**Edit**
Full Error code:

```
MissingMethodException: Method 'Clock.TEST' not found.
System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember (System.String name, 
System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder 
binder, System.Object target, System.Object[] providedArgs, 
System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers, 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.String[] namedParams) 
(at <d4cde64232cf45659d86aafa597faa77>:0)
System.Type.InvokeMember (System.String name, 
System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder 
binder, System.Object target, System.Object[] args) (at 
<d4cde64232cf45659d86aafa597faa77>:0)
Clock.InvokeByName (System.String typeName, System.String methodName, 
System.Object target) (at Assets/Scripts/Clock.cs:31)
Clock.Tick (System.String method, System.String methodName, 
System.Object target) (at Assets/Scripts/Clock.cs:38)
Clock.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/Clock.cs:58)
```

Comment: The type name must be the fully qualified type name including the namespace.

Comment: i dont use any namespace for the class clock, i dont think thats the issue, can u develop a bit more your idea?

Comment: Can you expand first on where the code is failing. You write that you call the Set_Tick method which only sets parameters. What are you doing next and what happens next? If a member isn't found, you should get an exception.

Comment: Added the full error code, the Ticks are called using a countdown, i need to improve this but right now is only a FixedUpdate countdown and reset of an int value

Comment: To improve the question for anyone who comes across this later: The exception says that you are calling the Tick() method, not the Set_Tick() method. Maybe you can add the tiny main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide one more flag - `BindingFlags.Instance` to the invoke call:

```
return callType.InvokeMember(methodName,
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
            defaultBinder, target, new object[] { });
```

Comment: Thanks, after 2 days it finally worked :D

Tested whit multiples scripts outside the Clock and works fine,

Comment: @VicenteGarcíaAndrade was glad to help! Note that in general reflection is quite slow and depending on usecase can have measurable effect on performance. I would say in this case you can try looking into using `Func<object>` instead of dynamic call binding. At least based on provided code.

Comment: I'd think that Action would be better here than Func<object>, because TEST is void with no parameters.

Comment: hmm thanks for the reply i would give those methods a good look, and see how they work (:

Comment: I've added Action to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your call to `InvokeMember` you are not specifying that the method should search all members of the object instance. Add `BindingFlags.Instance` as an additional binding flag:

```
return callType.InvokeMember(methodName, 
   BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, 
   defaultBinder, target , new object[] { }
);
```

Action is faster (at least for multiple invocations) and more readable than Reflection. Here's what your sample would look like with Action.

Clock.cs

```
public class Clock
{
    private Action TickAction = null!;
    
    public void Tick()
    {
        TickAction();
    }

    public void Set_Tick(Action tick)
    {
        TickAction = tick;
    }

    public void TEST()
    {
        Console.Write("TEST");
    }    
}
```

Program.cs

```
var clock = new Clock();
clock.Set_Tick(clock.TEST);
clock.Tick();
```